# How do I check I copied a bunch of files and folders correctly from an MTP device?

Tags: windows, backup, android, hashing, mtp

That. Windows 10 Home, Android 7.1.2 device. I want to check if it copied right, as it's a backup.

Comment: What do you need to look for in the copied files? Making sure they copied right? Did you use a utility to make the backup?

Answer (score 1):

Checksums are the usual way this is handled.

Checksums are (mostly) unique number and letter combinations generated for a file via an algorithm. If a file changes (e.g it is corrupted during a transfer), the number and letter combinations change. Therefore, by generating these checksums both before and after a file transfer, we can compare them and spot possible corruption.

To use checksums, you need a program to generate them first. And while there are many checksum formats, one of the most common is called [md5](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and is the one you will most likely want to use.

**md5 Checksum Use**

For Android, you may want to check out [Hash Calc (Checksum Utility) by kevinhhl](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.kevinhhldev.hashcalc&hl=en). It will generate md5 format checksums in bulk for files in a directory and sub-directories.

I haven't tested it with Android 7 but it does work on Android 6.

If you do use Hash Calc above, for any files you intend to backup:

- Start Hash Calc and browse for files.
- Select a directory containing the files you intend to back up but do not select a particular file.
- Choose "Hash All" in the upper right, choose an option if you wish from the dialog (you don't have to select either) and press Start.
- From the next screen select "Generate Text File" (turn off "Show directory-path" ).
- Save the text file (Export then Save).

When you are ready to backup, copy the text file(s) you generated above along with the other files to your PC.

Finally, use a utility on your PC to check the transfered files against the md5 checksum file(s) you generated (the text files) .

There are a wide variety of programs that can do this on PC, but one that currently works with Windows 10 and is extremely easy to use is [HashCheck Shell Extension by Kai Liu](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/).

**Caveats**

- HashCheck Shell Extension expects the checksum text files you generate to have an ".md5" extension, not ".txt".

  So, assuming you want to be able to double click the file to do a check on your PC, either change the extension when you initially save the file on Android or rename it after you transfer it to the PC.
- Make sure that any checksum file is in the directory same directory as the backup file.

  If you used a multi-level directory on your phone, you may need to either recreate it or give the proper directories in the checksum file(s) by editing in e.g Notepad.

**Note**

About your situation specifically, just generate the checksum files (assuming the original items are still on your device), transfer those checksum files to the PC and check the backups as indicated.